# how to replace a value with a calculation in bash/sed

Tags: bash

I used bash sed to replace ip address in a group of files, 
i.e 10.1.1.x => 10.2.2.x-19:

```
file1: 10.1.1.29 => 10.2.2.10, 
file2: 10.1.1.30 => 10.2.2.11, 
file3: 10.1.1.31 => 10.2.2.12,
```

etc.

I almost managed with:

```
for file in ifcfg* ; do sed -e "s/10.1.1./10.2.2./" $file >tmp/$file ; done
```

but couldn't figure out how to calculate and replace the last address position (x => x-19)

it's probably really easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$ for file in ifcfg*; do
    num=$(grep IPADDR $file|awk -F. '{print $4}')
    sed -e "s/10.1.1.[0-9]\+/10.2.2.$(($num-19))/" $file >tmp/$file
  done
```

This takes the contents of the IP address and cut's it down so that it's the 4th octet, which is stored in the variable `$num`. This variable is then added with `19` during the `sed` command. I needed to expand your original `sed` a bit by adding a `[0-9]\+` to remove the existing 4th octet so that we could just replace it with `$num+19`.

Comment: Thanks, but got error message "sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: @rookie - can you share what the lines look like that contain the IP addresses? Are you running this under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*`?

Comment: the lines look like IPADDR=10.1.1.x
and yes, sort of, I want to change in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*, but am playing in a copied folder so far

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!!! Just what I needed when left alone at the office... Lots of sunshine to you :-)

Comment: @rookie - thanks please mark it as the accepted answer and upvote if you think it was helpful and the most appropriate answer for your question, so others know that you issue's been resolved. Same to you!

Answer (score 3):

You will have better luck doing this with awk rather than sed.

```
awk -F. '{printf ("%d.%d.%d.%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$NF-19)}'
```

or as per your example,

```
awk -F. '/10.1.1/ {printf ("10.2.2.%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$NF-19)}'
```

or

```
for file in ifcfg*
do
    awk -F. '/10.1.1/ {printf ("10.2.2.%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$NF-19)}' $file >tmp/$file
done
```

To preserve the other lines and assuming that `x` is the last element on the line to be replaced, here is what you do

```
for file in ifcfg*
do
    awk -F. '/10.1.1/ {printf ("%s.%d.%d.%d\n",$1,2,2,$NF-19)}
             !/10.1.1/ {print $0}' $file > tmp/$file
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a bunch of files that are all the same:
a line with just 10.2.2.0 


and also I need to keep other lines in the original file, these are now overwritten with the awk. (With my sed command above, the old content was left, only the ip adress was changed)

Comment: Do you have other content on the same line?  You may have to tweak the print statement to preserve that content.

Comment: the other content is on other lines, and the line I want to change is really IPADDR=10.1.1.x

Comment: I just modified the answer above to take care of this.

Comment: OK, thanks, this works too. This forum is a great way to get help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$NF -= 19; print $0 > ("tmp/" FILENAME)}' ifcfg*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl for this:

```
$ grep '10\.' file[123]
file1:10.1.1.29
file2:10.1.1.30
file3:10.1.1.31

$ perl -i -pe 's/10\.1\.1\.(\d+)/ "10.2.2." . ($1 - 19) /ge' file[123]

$ grep '10\.' file[123]
file1:10.2.2.10
file2:10.2.2.11
file3:10.2.2.12
```